# Lookup from a Vuex observed property containing many rows is very slow

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to render a long list of items through a number of fixed cells in a home made grid with around 50 fixed rows.

When I scroll I read out different values from a Vuex store data property that holds an array of around 5000 rows.

So it is important to understand that I do **not** create new cells or rows, *Once created I merely update their content upon scrolling.* see below:

```
<template>
    <div ref="mygridcell" class='vg-data-cell' v-bind:style='mhstyle'>
            
        <span>{{ thevalue }}</span>

    </div>
</template>

...partial...

export default Vue.extend({
    props: ['rowNo', 'colDef', 'rowNoVis'],
    data: () => new MyData(),
    computed: {
        thevalue (): string {
            let row = this.$store.state.rowsPrepared[this.rowNo];
            return row["lastName"];
        },
```

I am using a Vuex store and have a property on its state called 'rowsPrepared' that contains an array of 5000 rows.

#### The problem

When I start scrolling and read out the values for the cells through the 'rowsPrepared' Vuex property **it is dreadfully slow**.

However, if I read the data from a stand-alone static (non observed) data object containing the 5000 rows **it is super fast!**

So the issue seems that when reading like this:
`let s = store.rows[1255]["lastname"]`
is considerably slower than:
`let s = nonobserved.rows[1255]["lastname"]`

Why is reading from an 'observable' vuex property so slow and is there a way around it?

What I have done is attach the 'rowsPrepared' property *after the store is created* so it is not observed and indeed, scrolling is super fast.
However, if an item changes its value it is not automatically tracked so I will be forced to do a hacky refresh - stuff that is meant to be done by Vue itself!!

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is that in you are accessing the rowsPrepared from the store for every cell in the grid. So, what happens is that whenever there is a change anywhere in the rowsPrepared array the computed property gets triggered for each and every cell even if that cell's value hasn't been updated. You can verify this by putting a console in the computed property and I think you will see that console printed for every cell which makes scrolling heavy.

Solution :- You need to pass the rowsPrepared[this.rowNo]['lastName'] as a prop to your cell component instead of accessing it in every cell.

Something like :-

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in rowsPrepared">
 <CellComponent 
     v-bind:value=rowsPrepared[index]['lastName']
     v-bind:colDef = "colDef"
     v-bind:rowNoVi= "rowNoVi">
 </CellComponent> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but whilst that maybe the case it only does that for around 25 visible rows with each row showing 8 cells so that seems unlikely to be case - my question  really is about why Vuex is so slow when I access these rows if they are observed as opposed to reading them from a non observed list of rows.

So again, I do NOT update any data - I am just reading them!!!